# Create PIPE between web socket and tcp socket

Tags: websocket, python-3.6, python-asyncio

My service already uses Websockets to communicate with webserver
It also connects to the other tcp endpoint.

It does two things

1/
   => Reads the data from the webserver
   => write it to the tcp endpoint

2/ 
  => Reads the data from the tcp endpoint
  => write it to the webserver.

I have the following code to serve the purpose

```
import websocket
import asyncio


def open_remote(reader):
print("open remote")
    do_remote_read(reader)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print("message recieved")
    print(message)
    writer.write(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

async def do_remote_read(reader):
    print("remote read")
    data = await reader.read(1000)
    ws.send(data)
    print(data.decode())
    print ("remote exit")


def on_open(ws):
    print("websocket opened")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop();
    reader, writer = asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 2000,
                                                  loop=loop)
    asyncio.sleep(3)
    loop.run_until_complete(open_remote(reader))


websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://x.x.x.x:/abc",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
ws.on_open = on_open
ws.run_forever()
```

In this code once the websocket is opened, callback on_open gets called 
where it tries to open other remote endpoint and it gets me the following error.

```
websocket opened
error from callback <function on_open at 0x7f398e3d96a8>: yield from wasn't used with future
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websocket/_app.py", line 345, in _callback
    callback(self, *args)
  File "websocket_python.py", line 40, in on_open
    loop=loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/streams.py", line 81, in open_connection
    lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 748, in create_connection
    yield from tasks.wait(fs, loop=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 313, in wait
    return (yield from _wait(fs, timeout, return_when, loop))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 396, in _wait
    yield from waiter
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of error is that `asyncio.open_connection` is a coroutine, so you must await it or, since `on_open` is not async, run it with `run_until_complete`:

```
reader, writer = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.open_connection(...))
```

Also note that just calling `asyncio.sleep(3)` does nothing unless you await it from a coroutine. (Calling `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(3))` is possible, but it boils down to a very fancy way of writing `time.sleep(3)`.)